# Redundant newlines are created in Excel cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

We use Excel 2013 in Windows(8 and 10) and have been experiencing the following problems.

- We enter text with newlines in some cells and share the xlsx files. So far so good, but when we double-click some of the cells and select text using Ctrl-A and copy and paste to other application, every newline becomes double (two newlines).
- Every newline becomes double in some cells when the files are opened in Excel in Mac.
- When we output CSV files, it looks fine. No duplicated newlines.

Obviously some kind of CR/LF compatibility issue exists here.  The question is, how can we detect and/or prevent this?  I thought it might be a common problem but it seems that I can't find any information about this.

Comment: What "other application" are you pasting into? Also is it possible for you to provide the CSV file to take a look at?

Comment: It hurts when I lift my arm. Doctor: Don't lift your arm. Try exporting your information, then importing rather than copy/paste. You can also link the information. There are many creative ways to do this.

Comment: How are the newlines getting into the Excel cells? Alt-Enter, or copy/paste from a different application?

Answer (score 0):

Try use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> to select all our data against using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

I could probably affirm the "other application" you are pasting at uses a different **EOL** (End Of Line) character. It happens usually when you copy data from a **Windows** based systems to a ***NIX** system. For instance **LF** is used in **Linux**, **CR** in **MacOS** and **Windows** usually combines both **CRLF** for a single line break.
You can read about it with more detail at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline)